# R: Sorting two times in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame X(sample):

```
  VariableA     VariableB   VariableC
1    0            A                13
2    0            B                10
3    1            B                 1
4  1.5            C                 1
5   10            A                64
6   10            B                 1
7   5             C                 3
```

and I would like to sort the data with respect first to `VariableB` and after to `VariableA`. To be more clear my output should be like this:

```
  VariableA     VariableB   VariableC
1    0            A                13
5   10            A                64
2    0            B                10
3    1            B                 1
6   10            B                 1
4  1.5            C                 1
7   5             C                 3
```

I tried the following:

```
Output <- X[order(X$VariableB,X$VariableA),]
```

which sorts only with respect of the `VariableB`. (Additional Info: Both `VariableA` and `VariableB` are of type Factors.

Comment: For reproducibility, it may be better to post the output of `dput` i.e. `dput(X)` as the solutions may depend on the order of factor levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the first variable to 'numeric' and the second to 'character' inside the `order` and it should work

```
df1[order(as.character(df1$VariableB), as.numeric(as.character(df1$VariableA))),]
```

Comment: Compining the two answers I used the following: `arrange(X,VariableB,as.numeric(as.character(VariableA)))` . The `variableB` do not need to be converted to character.

Comment: @MpizosDimitris It depends on the factor level order of `VariableB` as I stated in the comments.  Suppose if the levels are `C, A, B`, then the order will be different, which you didn't show in the post

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The factors in `VariableB` where ordered alphabetically which made me believe that it was the correct answer by using `arrange`

Comment: @MpizosDimitris  In that case, it should work with `arrange`, what I am saying that the info about the alphabetic order of the factor is not given in your post

Comment: @MpizosDimitris  I think the reason why you need `as.numeric(as.character` for the VariableA may be related to the order of levels for that variable

Answer (score 0):

Using the dplyr package Use

```
arrange(x, VariabeB, VariableA)
```

Comment: This assumes that the factor order in VariableB is in `A, B,C` order.  This would fail if it is not in that order